# subprocess.Popen module getting output as a first line

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to implement a script for running shell command using subprocess module.
When i am taking input from file i am only getting the output as 1st line of command.
But for single input without taking from file i am getting the whole command output."
Looks like something messy in reading the output when taking input from file.
Please suggest.

Script for particular mac

```
import subprocess
out=subprocess.Popen(["macsearch","00:23:5f:5a:56:7b"])
print(out)
```

Output :- It will give complete output.

Script for taking input of macaddress from a file.

```
import subprocess
with open("mac.txt","r") as f:
     for line in f:
     out=subprocess.Popen(["macsearch", "line"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     print(out)
```

For this script i only get 1st line of the output.
Please suggest as i want complete output for the command.

Comment: As far as I know `print (out)` will print something like <subprocess.Popen object at 0x....>. To pass output to var, you have to run `.communicate` method https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: Okay i have tried communicate and getting the output but i am only getting 1st line as output and not the other lines of the command.

Comment: In `out=subprocess.Popen(["macsearch", "line"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` remove quotes from `"line"`. Also fix indent. If it still won't help, please attach few lines of your "mac.txt" file.

Comment: Thank you so much !!
That works..
Script is working now as expected.
import subprocess
with open("mac.txt","r") as f:
     for line in f:
     process=subprocess.Popen(["macsearch", "line"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     out=process.communicate()
     print(out)